# Default value of parameter schema text field does not appear in Template Builder

Tags: schema

I am trying to create a simple parameter schema that has one mandatory text field with a default value of "xxxx". I am using this parameter schema on one of my template building blocks in order to allow passing in a text value that is used in that TBB. This is a very basic, typical scenario.

But when I open my template in template builder and look at the TBB, it does have the parameter from the schema, but it is not populated with the default value. Is this expected behaviour, a bug in Tridion, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

This is a known limitation in Template Builder. It doesn't look at the default value defined in the Schema, so you'll need to handle the default in the TBB itself.

Comment: Should be documented too, but I didn't bother to look it up ;o)

Comment: I don't think it's documented. Under known issues, the only relevant one is that it doesn't validate mandatory fields (which is another thing your TBB needs to handle!)

Comment: Ah you are right, I expected it to be mentioned with the unsupported field types, as unuspported properties. We should probabaly add a comment to the documentation about it.